# one functionality for opening different modal popups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to open a modal popup

```
const videoModal = $('#videoModal');

$('.modal-btn').on('click', event => {
    const button = event.target.closest('.modal-btn');
    const link = $(button).data('video');

    openModal(link);
});

function openModal(link) {
    videoModal.modal('show');
    $('#video iframe').attr('src', link);
}
```

Then I needed to add another modal popup, there are different styles and buttons, but the opening functionality is the same, so I added the code

```
const videoModalSs = $('#videoModalSs');

$('.modal-btn-ss').on('click', event => {
    const buttonSs = event.target.closest('.modal-btn-ss');
    const linkSs = $(buttonSs).data('video');

    openModalSs(linkSs);
});

function openModalSs(linkSs) {
    videoModalSs.modal('show');
    $('#video iframe').attr('src', linkSs);
}
```

But in fact, all the code here is identical, and the only thing that differs is the name of variables and functions

The question is, is it possible to make this functionality work for two modal popups, while not repeating its code 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the event listeners in a loop that iterates over only the parts that change.

```js
for (const [btnClass, modalId] of [['.modal-btn', '#videoModal'], ['.modal-btn-ss', '#videoModalSs']]) {
    const videoModal = $(modalId);
    $(btnClass).click(event => {
        const button = event.target.closest(btnClass);
        const link = $(button).data('video');
        videoModal.modal('show');
        $('#video iframe').attr('src', link);
    });
}
```